# Why {Home} ads a space in AutoHotKey snippet?

Tags: autohotkey

Why {Home} (and {End}) ads a space in AutoHotKey snippet? It is completely counterintuitive.

```
::a::
Send,
(
aaaa
aa
)
Send {Up} {Home}
return
```

I get:

```
aa aa
aa
```

Very strange.

Comment: Because there is a space in the command `Send {Up} {Home}` between {Up} and {Home}. Remove it.

Comment: @user3419297 Maybe post this as an answer since it is exactly the answer.